# AngularJS directive doesn't set 2nd level of scope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

I'm using a directive to read json data from a `<script>` element, this works fine as long as my `ng-scope` is a first level property like `data`. For some reason I'm not getting the data in 2nd or deeper level property of my object, for example `data.search`. I guess it's again some weird scope issue I have or I don't yet fully understand.

Why is it setting the first level but not 2nd level property?

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j181joh4NQguybx6HRiP?p=preview)**

**JS**

```
angular.module('app', [

]);

angular.module('app').directive('jsonData', [function () {
        return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {
                        scope[attributes.ngModel] = JSON.parse(element.html());
                }
        };
}]);

angular.module('app').controller('TestController', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.searchTest = {};

        $scope.data = {
            search: {
            }
        };
    }]);
```

**Markup:**

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/angular.js/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="TestController">

        <style>
          pre { border: 1px solid red; padding: 5px ;}
        </style>

        <h3>2nd level</h3>
        <script type="application/json" json-data ng-model="data.search">
           {"price_from":"3","price_to":"412"}  
        </script>
        <pre>{{data.search | json}}</pre>

      <h3>1st level</h3>
       <script type="application/json" json-data ng-model="data">
           {"price_from":"3","price_to":"412"}  
        </script>
        <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think that the second call to the directive (first level) overrides the all data object...

Comment: Also something with the 'scope[attributes.ngModel] ' is not right.
It will translate to scope['data.search'] which i think is different then scope.data.search

Comment: why would you ever need to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Kinnza yes it does override the whole object, that's why I want the 2nd level property of it. How would I avoid that it writes it to `scope['data.search']` instead of `scope.data.search`` @charlietfl because we don't use Angular in a SPA.

Comment: seems completely backwards. Why can't you just pass all the data as a javascript variable in a javascript script tag . Still not clear what problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @charlietfl just because it's not a SPA it's not "backwards". We don't want to use Jquery because 1/3 of the code will become selectors and a mess. Angular is much cleaner and the directives are awesome and work great especially outside of a SPA! And this app is old, it can't be turned in a SPA within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Doesn't matter that it's not an SPA. `var data = {"price_from":"3","price_to":"412", search: {"price_from":"3","price_to":"412"}}` is all you seem to be doing. Then `angular.extend($scope, data)`

Comment: @charlietfl you're welcome to review the project and improve it if you're interested in working on it voluntary. ;) `var data = {...}` will not end up in the scope of my controller and I need it there.

Comment: Yes it will .. you simply extend the scope `angular.extend($scope, data)` . Angular is still javascript and anything in global namespace can be accessed anywhere

Comment: It is not really best practice to throw everything into the global namespace. Also it will tight couple my controller to the availability of that variable.

Comment: OK..whatever, having the view create the scope is pretty abstract vs one data object in the page

Comment: It doesn't create it, it sets data to the already existing scope of the controller. To get the same data in a service via the $http service I would have to do a lot work in the backend as well while it is already available inside the response. Doesn't make sense to go that way because of the unnecessary amount of work, it doesn't make sense from an economic point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Kinnza who figured out the cause I found a way of doing it in Angular:

I've replaced

```
scope[attributes.ngModel] = JSON.parse(element.html());
```

with

```
$parse(attributes.ngModel).assign(scope, JSON.parse(element.html()));
```

and it works well now.

Answer (score 0):

First change the directive to something like this:
                  var text = 'scope.'+attributes.ngModel+'='+element.html();
                  eval(text);

Im not sure its the best way but it will work better then scope[attributes.ngModel]

In order for it not to override the all object you need something other than assigning to the object.
Something like underscore _.extend can work.